# Correct way to define a constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

I am trying to follow the MDN article Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

In there it defines a constructor as:

```
var Person = function(firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
}
```

and

```
function Student(firstName, subject) {
  // Call the parent constructor, making sure (using Function#call)
  // that "this" is set correctly during the call
  Person.call(this, firstName);

  // Initialize our Student-specific properties
  this.subject = subject;
}
```

Why is the Student constructor not defined as:

```
var Student = function(firstName, subject) {
  // Call the parent constructor, making sure (using Function#call)
  // that "this" is set correctly during the call
  Person.call(this, firstName);

  // Initialize our Student-specific properties
  this.subject = subject;
}
```

Comment: I'm struggled to see the difference.

Comment: The difference is one is using a function declaration whereas the other is using a function expression. If I understand correctly, the function expression is hoisted differently. In this case though I could probably use either?